# require_once path can't locate file?

Tags: php, require

Here is my folder structure as example:

```
source files/
    controller/
        ctrl_showData.php
    model/
        Database.class.php
```

Suppose it's now in controller directory, and in the ctrl_showData.php, I want to require the Database.class.php, so I try:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) .'/../model/Database.class.php');
```

But when I debug, the program stalls when it execute the statement above, which I guess it can't locate the file. I already read similar questions and tried their solutions, but none work. Any one could help? Thanks!
Here is the echo result:

```
/controller/../model/Database.class.php
```

Apparently, it doesn't go the parent directory, which is the source files/, then go to the model/ , but don't know why?

Thanks for the error message suggestions, the error message is:

```
Warning: require_once(config/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /model/Database.class.php
```

Because I also require the the config.php in the database file, which the path is not correct. I didn't think about that, thank you for all your help!

Comment: What does the full path result in? Can you show it instead of requiring?... Anyway, if it can't find the file, it shouldn't stall but throw a fatal error

Comment: To **Pekka's** point, `echo dirname(__FILE__) .'/../model/Database.class.php';` and see if it's the expected path.

Comment: require_once looks fine... Please post the error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..') . '/model/Database.class.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using:

```
include('./model/Database.class.php')
```

Comment: This won't work if the file he's doing this in is included from another file in another directory.

Comment: It seems work. Now the program doesn't stall when it execute it. Thanks!

Comment: The program didn't stall, but it didn't include the database file, because when I try to initial the object of database, it stalls again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relative path, so using this (below) should just be working:

```
require_once('../model/Database.class.php');
```

Comment: Not if the file he's doing this in is included from another file in another directory.

Comment: @Pekka even that would work, as PHP accepts relative paths to form every file

Comment: Nope. A path is always relative to the current working directory. If you include a file from a file in another directory, the latter one will be the working directory.

Comment: one last comment on that from me: It does work in everything I have build so far. If documentation says otherwise, then it probably is a bug, but it does work for me all the time (also on the latest stable versions)

Comment: I guarantee you 100% that it doesn't work (I've done this so often that I'm absolutely positive). Maybe you have an include path set in your projects?

Comment: I tried this, didn't work, it might be the situation that @Pekka mentioned, though I don't really understand the concept.

Comment: Everyone here is true only up to the fact that the file called is really the one he says. In MVC, everything goes throught a routing unit and you will include everything from there. So yes, in some cases the include('../Models/file.php') could work, but since this looks like and MVC app, it most probably wouldn't in the current context...

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping that call in realpath() http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

If your path isn't resolving correctly it will return null, and it cleans up the relative path mess you have in the middle.

Comment: I tried this: require_once(realpath(__DIR__).'/../model/Database.php'), but still the same.

Comment: what do you get if you <?php echo realpath(dirname(__FILE__) .'/../model/Database.class.php'); ?>?

Answer (score 0):

What is the error in your error log? Do you get something that says the file can't be found? Do you get an error at all?

Use:

```
error_reporting E_ALL
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

And then see what is the error. If your error is really about including a missing file, check that the path is right, also check that your include path is right. You could by error have removed the "." in the include_path directive or your CMS could have done so if it wants to restrict you to using their autoloader.

Another idea is to EXIT('BLA') in your file and call your page again to see if the BLA appears, if it does, it means your file is included but there is bug in it and thats why you stall.